# EF6 fluent relation with custom foreign key and FK property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to migrate existing project to EF and already have strict database structure and mandatory set of properties. The problem I now fight with is on the following.

I have two classes:

```
public class Entity
{
    public virtual long ID {get;set;}
    public virtual long ContragentID {get;set;}
    public virtual Contragent {get;set;}
}

public class Contragent
{
    public virtual long ID {get;set;}
    public virtual long EntityID {get;set;}
    public virtual Entity {get;set;}
}
```

With the following entity mappings:

```
    public class ClassContragentAccountMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Contragent>
{
    public ClassContragentAccountMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        HasKey(t => t.ID);
        // Table & Column Mappings
        ToTable("contragent");
        Property(t => t.ID).HasColumnName("id");        
        Property(t => t.EntityID).HasColumnName("e_id");    

        HasOptional(t => t.Entity).WithOptionalDependent(t => t.Contragent);
    }
}

public class ClassLegalEntityAccountMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Entity>
{
    public ClassLegalEntityAccountMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        HasKey(t => t.ID);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        ToTable("entity");
        Property(t => t.ID).HasColumnName("id");
        Property(t => t.ContragentID).HasColumnName("contragentid");
    }
}
```

The problem is that relation throws an exception that Entity_ID column is not found. Is there a way to specify FK for the relation as attributes seems to not work here? I've also tried to use:

```
HasOptional(t => t.Entity).WithOptionalDependent(t => t.Contragent).Map(t=> t.MapKey("e_id"));
```

But then it conflicts with the already defined 'e_id' property. And I need both relation and the property present.

Is there any way to specify FK for relation and preserve ID properties in classes?

Comment: Can you add the table DDL, and try to reverse-engineer the schema into an EF model and see what that generates?

Answer (score 0):

Probably I can go with remaking relation ID properties:

```
public virtual long ContragentID => Contragent?.ID;

public virtual long EntityID => Entity?.ID;
```

But I want to know is there any other way to do it.